# How to stitching this two images become like the template image

Tags: python, opencv

Below the code I use to get the image keypoint. One image is the template, and the other is for testing different angles [matching](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cm3xd.png) to match them together.
But when matching the image, the output does not match correctly. [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Gqhc.png).
I want the output to look like the original image. What is wrong with my code? Is there any advice you can give me?

```
im1 = [cv2.imread(file) for file in natsorted(glob.glob("/content/drive/MyDrive/fyp/test1/template1/tmp_002.png"))]
im2 = [cv2.imread(file) for file in natsorted(glob.glob("/content/drive/MyDrive/fyp/test2/query1/tmp_002 (1).png"))]

images_list=list()
img_number = 0
for item in im1:
  img_gray= cv2.cvtColor(item, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
  images_list.append(img_gray)
  img_number += 1
 
images_list1=list()
img_number1 = 0
for item1 in im2:
  img_gray= cv2.cvtColor(item1, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
  images_list1.append(img_gray)
  img_number += 1

i=0
for item ,item1 in zip(images_list,images_list1):
  orb = cv2.ORB_create(nfeatures=2000)

  keypoints1, descriptors1 = orb.detectAndCompute(item, None)
  keypoints2, descriptors2 = orb.detectAndCompute(item1, None)

  flann_index_lsh = 6
  index_params = dict(algorithm= flann_index_lsh,
                      table_number=12,
                      key_size=20,
                      multi_probe_level=2)
  search_params = dict(checks=100)

  flann = cv2.FlannBasedMatcher(index_params , search_params)

  flann_matches = flann.knnMatch(descriptors1 , descriptors2 , k=2)

  matches_mask = [[0,0] for i in range(len(flann_matches))]

  good= []
  for index in range(len(flann_matches)):
    if len(flann_matches[index]) ==2 :
      m ,n = flann_matches[index]
      if m.distance < 0.8 * n.distance :
       matches_mask[index] = [1,0]
       good.append(flann_matches[index])

  draw_params=dict(singlePointColor= (255,0,0), 
                  matchesMask= matches_mask,
                  flags=0)
  good_matches=[]
  for m1,m2 in good:
    if m1.distance < 0.8 * m2.distance:
        good_matches.append(m1)
  
  MIN_MATCHES=5
  if len(good_matches) > MIN_MATCHES:
    src_points = np.float32([keypoints1[m1.queryIdx].pt for m1 in good_matches])
    dst_points = np.float32([keypoints2[m1.trainIdx].pt for m1 in good_matches])
    m, mask = cv2.findHomography(src_points, dst_points, cv2.RANSAC)
    height ,width = item1.shape
    im1Reg = cv2.warpPerspective(item1, m, (width, height))

  img3= cv2.drawMatchesKnn(item, keypoints1 , item1 , keypoints2, flann_matches, None , **draw_params)
  cv2_imshow(img3)
  cv2_imshow(im1Reg)
  i += 1
```

Comment: bigger pictures would help, where the matches can actually be seen clearly. those thumbnails are useless. -- you seem to have very few matches. *stop* using ORB. use AKAZE instead. -- also check if you got `trainIdx` and `queryIdx` right in your `src_points` and `dst_points` lookup... use example code provided by opencv

Comment: is that flann matcher will better than bf matcher?

Comment: it's certainly less brute-force but quality is about the same. stick with flann.